# Calculating tier price

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

This is the example data:

```
100 items or less = $20
200 items or less = $15
500 items or less = $10
```

Example scenario:
user inputs `150` items -> price is $`15` per item

And this is how far I get:
http://jsfiddle.net/ByPh5/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

var tier_prices = {
    '100':'20',
    '200':'15',
    '500':'10'
}

var user_input = $('#user_input').val();

var price_output = 0;                    
/*
   calculate
*/

    $('#price_output').text(price_output)


})​

</script>

<input type="text" id="user_input" value="150"/>
<p id="price_output"></p>​
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: is it an option, to change the structure of tier_prices

Comment: multidimensional array is also fine

Comment: What is the unit price for 501 items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: Since you left some ambiguity, I'll assume that 500+ items also cost $20.)

Instead of messing with that data-structure, you can do something simpler. First the code, then the explanation (if the comments aren't enough.)

```
function determine_price ( qty ) {
    var prices = [
        20, //0 to 99
        20, //100 to 199
        15, //200 to 299
        15, //300 to 399
        15, //400 to 499
        10  //500+
    ];

    //divide by the common denominator
    //0-99 turn into 0,
    //100-199 turns into 1
    //200-299 turns into 2
    //and so on
    qty = Math.floor( qty / 100 );

    //check for 600+, which are the same as 500 (last array item)
    return prices[ qty ] || prices.pop();
}
```

100, 200 and 500 have something in common: They're multiples of 100. So we take an array, and treat each element as if it's a range of 100: the first element (0) is 0 to 99 items, second element (1) is 100 to 199 items and so forth. Then, for each input quantity, we divide by that common denominator, to find out in which range it falls, and grab the price corresponding to that quantity.

In the case of ambiguity, which is what happens for 600+ elements (the last element, element #6 is for 500-599), we simply take the last range's price.

No need for loops, just simple math.

Answer (score 3):

First, instead of specifying the max quantity for a price tier, specify the min quantity.  And define it as a sorted array so you can iterate through it.

```
var tier_prices = [
    { minQty: 0,   unitPrice: 20 },
    { minQty: 101, unitPrice: 15 },
    { minQty: 201, unitPrice: 10 }
];
```

Then, loop through the values until you get to a minimum quantity that is greater than the entered quantity:

```
var qty = +$('#user_input').val();
var price;
for (var i = 0; i < tier_prices.length && qty >= tier_prices[i].minQty; i++) {
    price = tier_prices[i].unitPrice;
}
$('#price_output').text(price * qty);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/ByPh5/3/

Comment: Best solution if you can change the data structure. Question, are you doing `+this.value` as an alternative to `parseInt`?

Comment: @Radu - `+` coerces a string to a number, the same way `!` coerces to boolean.  It's behaves more like `parseFloat()` than `parseInt()`. But, when operating on a boolean, it will coerce `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`.  Whereas `parseFloat(true)` returns `NaN`.

Comment: Additionally, `parseFloat("0abc")` returns `0`, but `+"0abc"` returns `NaN`.

Comment: One other important difference is in handling octals.  `+"012"` returns `12`, but `parseInt("012")` returns `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are nice but a bit annoying since you're not guaranteed to go through the values in order.

http://jsfiddle.net/radu/6MNuG/

```
$(function() {
    var tier_prices = {
        '100': '20',
        '200': '15',
        '500': '10'
    };

    $('#user_input').change(function() {

        var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10),
            price = 0,
            prevTier = 0,
            maxTier = 0;            

        for (var tier in tier_prices) {
            if (tier_prices.hasOwnProperty(tier) && num <= tier) {
                if (tier < prevTier || prevTier == 0) {
                    price = tier_prices[tier];
                    prevTier = tier;
                }
            }

            if (tier > maxTier) maxTier = tier;
        }

        if (num > maxTier) price = tier_prices[maxTier];

        $('#price_output').text(price * num);
    });
})​;​
```

Example with a multidimensional array: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/6MNuG/

```
$(function() {
    var tier_prices = [
        [100, 20],
        [200, 15],
        [500, 10]
    ];

    $('#user_input').change(function() {
        var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10),
            price = 0,
            n = tier_prices.length - 1;

        if (num > tier_prices[n][0]) {
            price = tier_prices[n][1];   
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {                   
                if (num <= tier_prices[i][0]) {
                    price = tier_prices[i][1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $('#price_output').text(price * num);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var tier_prices = {
    '100': '20',
    '200': '15',
    '500': '10'
}
var price_output = 0;
var multiplier = 1;
$('#user_input').change(function() {
    var user_input = parseInt($('#user_input').val(),10);
    for (tier in tier_prices) {
        if (user_input <= tier) {
            multiplier = tier_prices[tier];
            break;
        }
    }
    $('#price_output').text(user_input * multiplier);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ByPh5/1/)**

### UPDATE

Here's an example forgoing the object you had with a simple switch/case since the idea of the object isn't very popular or functional. Note that I added a case for quantities greater than 500:

```
$('#user_input').change(function() {
    var user_input = parseInt($('#user_input').val(), 10);
    switch (true) {
    case user_input >= 0 && user_input <= 100:
        $('#price_output').text(user_input * 20);
        break;
    case user_input > 100 && user_input <= 200:
        $('#price_output').text(user_input * 15);
        break;
    case user_input > 200 && user_input <= 500:
        $('#price_output').text(user_input * 10);
        break;
    case user_input > 500:
        $('#price_output').text(user_input * 5);
    }
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ByPh5/5/)**

Comment: "There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited." - MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @Radu - true, and while I personally wouldn't use an object for it, I'm just going by what the OP posted and asked for. Plus, in testing, `for...in` does follow the order given, MDN's warning aside. At least in my experience.

Comment: Also, breaks for `user_input > 500`

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for a similar thing and decided to do it slightly different, ran it in js fiddle and it seems to work pretty well. As gilly3 pointed out you probably don't want an upper limit, so you might want to do '1 or more, 100 or more...500 or more'.  The vars and div names I used were different but you can see what I'm trying to do and adapt it to your needs:

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vx4k2vdh/5/**

```
(function() {
    const tiers = {
        0: 20,
        100: 15,
        200: 10,
        500: 5
    }

    /**
     * Take qty and return the first appropriate
     * tier that it encounters, break when
     * tier has been identified so you don't
     * waste time iterating if u've already found tier
    **/
    function calculatePriceTier(qty) {
        var selectedTier;
        for (var tier in tiers) {
          if (tiers.hasOwnProperty(tier)) {
            if (qty < tier) break;
            selectedTier = tier;
          }
        }
        return selectedTier;
     }

    $(function() {
        /**
         * Every time a new number is selected
         * run calculations and grab tier, total
        **/
        $('#items').on('input', 'input', function() {
            var qty = +$(this).val(),
                tier = calculatePriceTier(qty),
                total = qty * tiers[tier];
            $('#total-price span').text(total);
        });
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

What is described in the OP's request is volume pricing.
All the examples given here are for volume pricing not tier pricing.

Tire pricing example in ruby 
https://repl.it/repls/IndigoRightDisks

```
def cost(qty)

tier = {
    10   => 100,
    50   => 97,
    100  =>82,  
    200  =>71,
    300  =>66,
    400  =>64,
    500  =>27,
    1000 =>12
    }

  cs = []
  for cnt in 1..qty
    d = tier.keys.find{|x| cnt  <= x ?cnt <= x :  tier.keys.last == x }    
    cs << tier[d]
  end
  return cs.reduce{|y,x| y+x};
end
```